# gsutil: Could not acquire lock c:\gsutil\.gsutil\credcache.lock in 0 seconds

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I try to run next command `python c:\gsutil\gsutil ls` but i get error `Could not acquire lock c:\gsutil\.gsutil\credcache.lock in 0 seconds`

This file exists and has no readonly attribute.

Why I get this error?

Can you help me?

Thanks!

[image: error]

Comment: Can you send the output of 'gsutil -D ls' to gs-team@google.com?  In the meantime, what happens if you delete c:\gsutil\.gsutil\credcache and re-run?

Comment: @TravisHobrla, thank you for email address. Nothing changed after deleting this file.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar error come up with the credentials.lock file. I deleted the file and ran `gcloud auth login`. Worked perfectly after that.